# How to load DICOM CD/DVD used as a USB faster?

Tags: performance, dvd, compact-disc

So I'm using a DVD like a USB flash drive:

[image]

to carry radiological DICOM imaging and auto-play software for the imaging. The problem is, the images take a long time (three minutes) to completely load in the software when using a DVD. When I load the same software and images from a USB, the images load nearly instantly inside the software.

I have made sure that the DICOMDIR file is correct.

**What changes can I make to the CD disk to make it faster?** (It is not possible to change my system at all, nor use a USB, it has to be a CD/DVD). Things that I have thought of:

- Somehow caching the images on the DVD
- Using a mastered disk (the other option on the image I linked to)
- Some kind of faster CD/DVD that I'm not aware of
- Using a CD instead of a DVD

Specifics:

- The software is [Radiant CD/DVD Autorun Package](http://www.radiantviewer.com/dicom-viewer-manual/index.html?cd_dvd_autorun_package.htm)
- The images total 136MB and are of a CT scan
- The DVD is a DVD-R 4.7 GB with 16x recording speed

Any recomendations?

Comment: One big difference between flashdrives/pendrives and CD/DVD is that the latter is bad a random access. Thus this question: Does the CD/DVD sounds as if it makes lots of seeking operations?

Comment: @Hennes Yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CDROM usually has a single recording on it, writting in a single track that spirals over the whole disk. That works fine when reading sequentially (e.g. when playing audio from a music CD or copying or reading a single large file).

However if you have software which does not read things sequentially then it gets interesting. The easiest nion technical example I can offer is reading a a book like this:

Sequential: read word after word on the same page. Occasionally turn a page when you get to the end of a page.

Random: Read one world from a page 1, turn to page 213 and read a word, turn to page 73 and read a sentence, turn to page 314 and read ....  That will be much slower.

For this reason great care is taken on how data gets written to a CD or DVD, allowing music to be read, or movies to be read sequentially while muxed with subtitles or alternate languages.  For raw computer data this kind of work is not normally done. Instead files get written nicely sequential and you should be able to read and copy them at nice speeds.

That assumes that your viewer does read sequentially. If it does not it will cause lots of seeking, which is very slow on a CD/DVD and performance will be quite bad.

Possible solutions:

1. (for completeness sake): Do not use optical media. Not an option in your case since you explicitly stated this is not a choice in your post.
2. Copy data from the CD to another place (at high sequential speed) and then open them from another place.  Something like copy *.dicom to %tmp% && dicon_viewer.exe open %tmp%\image.dicom && clean copied images so %tmp% does not fill up over time.
3. (Weak option) Get faster CD drives.

These already match with your ideas:

```
Somehow caching the images on the DVD
```

Copying them to a temp location is effectively caching then on your desktops SSD/HHD. And depending on the OS and other activity they may also be in the OS's disk cache at just after copying.

```
Using a mastered disk (the other option on the image I linked to)
```

Possible. But then you need to reliably predict the access pattern to the DICOM files, write a custom ISO/UDF. Technically possible but requiring deep knowledge.

```
Some kind of faster CD/DVD that I'm not aware of
```

There is a limit to how fast the readers can get. Spin a disk to fast and it falls appart. Pratical max speeds seems to be about 60x audio read speed for a CDROM and about 16x for DVDs.  (note that the x60 and x16 are no comparable. for the CDROM it is compared to the normal speed of reading from an audio CDROM (about 150kb/sec for x1) and for a DVD is is compared to the much faster speed of reading a movie from the DVD).

```
Using a CD instead of a DVD
```

Should not make a diffrence.

You could test if your speed goes up when you write with a high quality writer and at lower speeds. In ye old era using a plexwriter at single speed burn produced CD with less errors and thus less need to error correction. But that only helps if your current setup is non optimal.

Lastly, check if the DVDreader is connected via normal AHCI and not via legacy mode. That allows the computer to send more than one command at the same time.

In book terms:

Legacy mode:
read page 1. Wait till done.
read page 200. Wait till done.
read page 2. Wait till done.

AHCI:
read pages 1 and 200 and 2.
(A smart device will read 1, 2 and then 200, but return 1, 200 and then 2, but with no additional seeks needed to track all the way back across the disk to page 2).

These kind of tricks worked perfect in old SCSI and current SAS disks. SATA-II  and upward also have these, though I do not know if a random DVD will make use of them. (unlike high performance server disks or SSDs).  Worth trying though.